# Delphi XE4 Collapsed ListView Group

Tags: delphi, listview, delphi-xe4

I have a `TListView` with 2 Columns - each are autosized. As soon as I add items to a group, the group collapses (`lgsCollapsed`). Unfortunately this looks a little "ugly" due to bad alignment in the ListView:

[image: ListView]

It automatically "hides" the little [+/-] toggle and I don't know why.
I'm not even sure if that's on purpose or just a bug...
When I change the size (width) of the Listview on runtime it realigns and the toggle comes back just fine (or when I move the slidebar). How can I realign / bring back the little toggle right after a new item has been added?

Comment: Not-autosizing to get rid of h-scroll bar can be fixed (qc 85132). Dunno if that would affect collapsing and even what it is :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are autosizing the columns, so there is likely an item in the group that is making the column grow larger then you want.  You can resize the `TListColumn.Width` as needed after adding the group/items to make sure the columns do not exceed the ListView's client area.  Call `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL)` to get the width of the vertical scrollbar and subtract that from the `TListView.ClientWidth` value, and then loop through the `TListView.Columns` (or just access the last `TListColumn`) to adjust each column's `Width` as needed so that the total of all the widths does not exceed the calculated client area.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) In my case the trick was access the Listview's width and set it to 0. Due to `alClient` it realigned just fine :)

Comment: Remy, there's VCL bug that prohibits LV realignment if only number of visible items changed, thus wrong results with (dis)appearing scrollbars if autosized columns used. But it can be fixed after 2 hours of debugging - see qc ref above ;-)